# How to read the time data from the csv file and plot a graph accordingly in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

the time format is  like this
               47:48.1
and here 47 minutes 48 seconds  1 millisecond

Comment: 1 milisecond or 100 milliseconds?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should get you started:

```
import csv
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y = [],[]
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('data.csv'))
for line in csv_reader:
    x.append(int(line[0]))
    y.append(dt.datetime.strptime(line[1],'%M:%S.%f'))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(y,x,'o-')
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Assuming `data.csv` file containing data like these:

```
0,43:48.1
1,45:13.1
2,47:50.1
3,55:02.3
```

Results in something like this:
[image]

Comment: How to include another column in displaying the labels of Y axis e.g time is [1] and some text from [2].

Answer (score 1):

The third part doesn't look like milliseconds, are you sure it's not just the decimal point for the second? If so, try this (where t_cvs is the string):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t_cvs = '23:12.1,24:59.2,26:09.4'  # or whatever

t1 = [t.split(':') for t in t_cvs.split(',')]
time = [60.*float(t[0]) + float(t[1]) for t in t1]

plt.plot(time)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

To read:

```
def convert(s):
  s = s.split(':')
  minutes = int(s[0])
  s = s[1].split('.')
  seconds = int(s[0])
  msec = int(s[1])
  return (60*minutes + seconds)*1000 + msec

fin = open(filename)
times = [convert(s) for s in fin.read().split(',')]
fin.close()
```

Note, if you have a *lot* of times, define the lambda as a function elsewhere.

Now `times` contains a list of integers (milliseconds) that you can plot as you would normally.